# Как вывести данные о файле

Tags: php

Есть галерея картинок, получаю их через форму от пользователя, и другим скриптом вывожу их циклом в карточках. Но еще нужно вывести название файла, размер и дату создания. Как вывести это одним циклом?

```js
<?php

$images = scandir('C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\include\upload');
$links = [];

foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($image === '.' || $image === '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $links[] = 'include/upload/' . $image;
}

foreach ($links as $link):?>
    <div class="col mb-4">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <img src="<?= $link ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="фото" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><?= $image ?> </h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        This is a longer card <?= $fileSize ?>
      </p>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
        Удалить
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago <?= $cardTime ?></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```